# Why do we have a red dialog for a success action?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, user-interface

Since the orange dialog are gone, we now have red dialog instead for (almost) everything (except [the blue one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u1a7.png) I guess).

I was wondering why the dialog is red when we just perform a valid action? Why not a green dialog instead? I feel wrong when I see the red dialog, like "*woops did I make something wrong?*".

**Color dialog that seems ok to me.**

When I voted to reopen a question on one I already voted for:

[image]

When I try to upvote my own answer:

[image]

**Color dialog that should wear a green color (or at least different than red)**

When I vote to close a question. As a *success* message, I got a red dialog. Err.

[image]

I do not find a question / or an answer to flag, but I guess the message will still be red.

With previous orange dialog, I didn't find the color wrong because it doesn't match a wrong/right action as red does.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167508/can-we-have-click-to-close-back-please

Comment: I thought it was a bit weird, given the whole reason for the borderless dialog window was to remove the scary red "error" appearance

Comment: Nice catch! +1 from QA)))

Comment: @Mat: I think the answer to that question better answers this one. That answer doesn't really address that question at all, in my opinion.

Comment: I liked the orange. It was a neutral colour with good contrast. It was of a good size and went away when you clicked on it. This looks like change for change's sake and it's turned into a bit of a _backwards step_.

Comment: Also, please bring back "click anywhere to close", I don't know who thought it was a good idea to limit it to the upper right X

Comment: @jmfsg: I already asked that [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167508/can-we-have-click-to-close-back-please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We no longer have one. Ever since Jeremy T added [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), we now have blue dialog boxes for successful actions:

[image]

Red is now reserved for unsuccessful actions and other bad stuff:

[image]