# "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-voting

Minor bug report here:

After voting a bit too fast, I saw the `You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds` error. Then I clicked the upvote button again quickly afterwards.

The error box moved up vertically about `20px`, but my vote submitted.

Error: Success!

[image: bug]

Comment: This bug also appears everytime you remove more than one comment in a short period of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error popup will disappear after a couple of seconds, and if you want it to disappear more quickly you can click anywhere within the error to close it.

This one is on the list, so if it hasn't been made auto fade yet, it will in the next few days .

Answer (score 5):

The new error messages do not close automatically when you click elsewhere on the page. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167508/can-we-have-click-to-close-back-please) for more on that topic.

The last time you clicked the vote arrow there was no error (presumably because the required 5 seconds had elapsed), but the old error message persisted on the page. You have to click the X icon to dismiss the error message.

Comment: Nice! As it happens, I've already upvoted that question.

Comment: Actually, it looks as though the error is regenerated on each click. I'm just basing that on trying to click the ✔ button to accept this answer, and getting a 'wait x mins' error. The error box fades out and in and is redrawn.

Comment: It seems I was just expecting the modal to close after x seconds/minutes...

Comment: The error now does get dismissed after every click.