# Should the comment voting time-throttle error fade automatically?

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, comment-voting

In the answer to [Can we have click-to-close back, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167508/can-we-have-click-to-close-back-please), two of the "New error styles" listed are:

> - Error, require action – These will be red and will need to be either manually closed or they will be closed automatically when we detect that the problem is solved (standard errors)
> - Error, no action required – These will be red and will fade out after one second. No    manual closing will be required (time-limited throttling errors)

I noticed that the comment voting time-throttle error (shown below) is of the former type, requiring a manual close. However, as this is a throttling error, shouldn't it be of the latter type, automatically disappearing?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, and we are working on this one and others.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize this was still a work-in-progress. Thanks.