# Same popup has different colors in Review/Main

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close, popups

After a [recent color change of the popups and error dialogs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167515/203389)  I noticed that some of the same popups were different colors depending on whether I was in review or not.

For example  close popups in review:

[image]

and from the main site outside of review:

[image]

As you can see, the ones in review are red/salmonish while the ones from the question itself are blue.

Is this a bug?  I haven't noticed it with any other popups, just the close ones.

I noticed today that the color for a flag wasn't blue either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next build will switch the error in review to use the correct popup color and behavior.

Comment: Can you please take a look on [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188241/152859)? Maybe the fix was applied only to this case and not to the case of daily vote limit?