# Inconsistent popup notification colors

Tags: support, voting, popups

I have noticed that the popup notification, "daily vote limit reached" has different colors depending (I assume) on how close the user is to being able to vote again. For instance, a user got this popup when he could vote again in a couple of minutes:

[image]

And this one when he was 9 hours from being able to vote again:

[image]

Is this by design? And if yes, do the different colours depend on time left to be able to vote again, or on some other variable? Are they randomly chosen?

I couldn't find anything on meta explaining this inconsistency (and by "inconsistency" I mean: sometimes the popup is blue, sometimes it is red, and I'd just like to understand why it changes).

Comment: Did you by any chance try to vote once from the question page and once from the review page? See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169981/152859)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm not completely sure, since the popups didn't appear to me, but to another user.

Comment: Please ask him/her then, it's pretty important information. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Will do and let you know when/if I get an answer. Thatnks for taking the time to address this question

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a by-design visual cue, something seen in various places around the network (though most of these are actually moderator-only).

Some of the elements on Stack Exchange sites use the following colorings (found in `all.css`):

```js
.cool {color:#999 !important;}
.warm {color:#9B764F !important;}
.hot {color:#CF7721 !important;}
.hotbg {background-color:#CF7721 !important;}
.supernova {color:#e01f1f !important;}
.supernovabg {color:#3c3927 !important;background-color:#fbe253;}
```

Basically, if it's a low value, it's blue. If it's a high value, it's red (not always true, but it seems to depend entirely on the metric)

Comment: Yeah, those apply to comment score and to the "characters left" when adding new comment. Good example of the different colors can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/152859). :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd many mod-tools-only things use them, too.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that! :)

Comment: It doesn't depend on value.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like message after the last vote is successfully applied is blue.
But when you try to vote above the limit the message is red.

Just checked - works as described:

[image: после применения последнего голоса]

[image: при попытке проголосовать ещё]